# Как сделать юнита на php + mysql?

Tags: php

Ну, вот хочу создать онлайн игру, и нужно как-то сделать юнита, помогите, пожалуйста.
Если можно, то подробно, а то я такого никогда не делал. Юнит должен иметь: Атаки и HP.
Заранее cпасибо. )

Comment: ппц честно, я угораю иногда с таких вопросов... начинают что-то делать, когда есть проработанный алгоритм и когда понятно, что куда и откуда. А вот так это все равно, что человек впервые читает книгу по ХТМЛ и сразу задает вопрос, а как сделать свой сайт, чтобы и почта своя была. Как это все написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да ладно, народ. Вот и пусть человек учится. Проще всего к книжкам послать.

```
class Unit{
const START_ATTACK_MIN = 1;
const START_ATTACK_MAX = 10;
const START_HP_MIN = 5;
const START_HP_MAX = 20;
const AMOUNT_OF_RACES = 5;
private $attack;
private $hp;
private $race;
  function __construct($attack=false,$hp=false,$race=false){
    if($attack===false){
      $this->attack = rand(START_ATTACK_MAX,START_ATTACK_MAX);
    }else{
      $this->attack = $attack;
    }
    if($hp===false){
      $this->hp = rand(START_HP_MAX,START_HP_MAX);
    }else{
        $this->hp = $hp;
    }   
    if($race===false){
      $this->race = rand(0,AMOUNT_OF_RACES);
    }else{
      $this->race = $race;
    }  
    //Как вариант - вфбрать минимаксы из таблицы характеристик расс:
    //| race_id | min_attack | max_attack | min_hp | max_hp | race_name | 
    //select `min_attack`,`max_attack`,`min_hp`,`max_hp` from `races` order by rand() limit 1
  }

  //Атакуем:
  function attack(&$unit_object){
    if($this->race != $unit_object->getRace()){
        $unit_object->hurt($this);
    }
  }

  //Нас бьют:
  function hurt(&$unit_object){
    $this->hp -= $unit_object->getAttack();  
    if($this->hp<1){
        $this->deth();
    }
  }

  //Получение величин:
  function getAttack(){
    return $this->attack;
  }
  function getRace(){
    return $this->race;
  }
  //Получать HP не надо: о здоровье должен знать только сам юнит.

  //Умираем:
  function deth(){
    //В простейшем случае, юнит просто дохнет.
    $this->__destruct();
    //В более сложном - говорит БД, что он сдох:
    //delete from `units` where id=`$this->id`
  }
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, что вы только добавите ему головной боли, и он поймет, что не надо учиться программировать, а легче нанять кого-нибудь. ))

Comment: Да, @Grimon прав... Ведь легче дружить с кодом, когда его делал сам, заранее продумав логику... Да и книжки почитать не повредит, а лишь позволит твердо стоять на "программных" ногах...

Comment: Ну, по крайней мере, я ответил на вопрос о принципе создания простейшего юнита с "Атаками и HP" :)))  
А какие выводы сделает человек.. Он, думаю, напишет: не удержится. Возможно, наоборот - понапакупает книжек и сделает крутую игруху за пару лет.  
Мой опыт знакомства с программированием тоже начался с того, что я поставил невообразимо сложную(по тем меркам) задачу и стал донимать всех вопросами.

Comment: @knes эт понятно.. Прост, как мне кажется, для человека было бы более полезно спросить "Каким образом это реализовать?" или "Что для этого необходимо?", что то в этом роде.. А в ответах навести человека на главные компоненты, чтоб он дальше про них узнавал... А если так всегда копипастить код, то мне кажется эт плохо выйдет.. Тем более человек пишет ".. такого никогда не делал!"...

Comment: А тут есть два варианта. Первый - человек хочет разобраться.  
Отлично! Надо кинуть ему код юнита без лишних деталей, чтобы он "читая чужой код" понял принцип. Если он будет сам разбираться в сложном "боевом" проекте, не имея достаточно опыта, точно все забросит.  
Второй: скопипастит.  
Флаг ему в руки. Через день/месяц/год придет сюда другой юзер, увидит ЭТОТ вопрос и уже сделает по первому варианту.

Comment: Ну почему же бросит? Если человек спрашивает, значит интересуется.. Прост, как я думаю ему нужно было бы начать с простого: 1. Создать юнита (простого, хотя бы кубик на экране). 2. Добавить движения (влево, вправо, вперед, назад). 3. Атака, прыжки и т.д. 4.Разные бонусы. Не так сложно, более понятно и опыт конечно же... По крайней мере, я бы так сделал...

Comment: Ну, еще не поздно поправить ваш [Ответ] на то, что вы написали. ;)

Comment: @knes с вашего позволения и по вашему совету;)

Comment: Всем спсибо, у всех , всего по чуть-чуть взял))

Answer (score 1):

Читайте книги, статьи, продумывайте алгоритмы, действия и пробуйте, экспериментируйте!) А будут проблемы в коде или в некоторых моментах, обращайтесь на форум... А если лень, наймите разработчика)

А посуществу начать с простого:

1. Создать юнита (простого, хотя бы кубик на экране).
2. Добавить движения (влево, вправо, вперед, назад).
3. Атака, прыжки и т.д.

4.Разные бонусы.

Не так сложно, более понятно и опыт конечно же...

Comment: Особенно интересно только на связке пхп-скул посмотреть на юнита) Ит маст би грейт фан)

Comment: А как правильно создать Атаки и хп в майскул?

Comment: MySQL - эт СУБД!! Единственное, что там можно сделать эт создать БД, а в ней таблицу с характеристиками юнита и тому подобное)