# Идеи онлайн игры

Tags: php

Хочу написать онлайн игру на чистом PHP+MySQL, какую-нибудь стратегию простенькую, а идей нет, подскажите свою или дайте пожалуйста ссылки где можно прочитать разные идеи, что да как. (сложность значения не имеет)

Comment: Волейбол. Хотя нет. Лучше типа ВОВ, но с казино и фуриями.

Comment: онлайн стратегия на php и мускуле???? работать будет через f5?

Comment: @RedMonkey наверно браузерная текстовая имеется ввиду.

Comment: javascript по любому нужен  
вообще было дело на хабре нашёл как делали [батлсити](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132362/), потом всем офисом рубались командно

Answer (score 4):

[Один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3015/prikol) тут уже [пытался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29447/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php-mysql). =)
Стратегий полно. Идеи лучше подсмотреть у признанных досовских игрушек: в них основной упор сделан именно на идеи, а не на графику или спецэффекты. Поверьте.
Современные браузерные игрухи так же можете изучить в плане вытягивания бабла. Травиан и аналоги - вполне себе нормальный вариант: можно играть бесплатно примерно до середины игры, потом платники резко становятся круче, играть становится скучно.

Comment: да, @Prikol это **легенда**, если вы понимаете о чем я :D

Comment: Я?!!! я чуть ли не лучше всех это понимаю. XD

Answer (score 2):

Напиши онлайн шахматы, шашки, домино и в таком духе... =)

Answer (score 1):

На чистом **PHP+MySQL** нормальную игру вы не напишете.

**С какой целью вы захотели написать игру?**

А вообще ищите идеи в поиске и на формах посвященных этой тематике - там больше будет целевых ответов.

Comment: На чистом PHP+MySQL нормальную игру вы не напишете// Спорно. Вялотекущие стратежки с ahah вполне можно написать без строчки на JS.

Comment: @knes, ключевое слово «**нормальную**».

Comment: это тоже нормальная. Нормальная != realtime and != action. 
Выращивание офощей или постройка зданий может длиться многие дни: зашел, отметил галками в форме, прошла проверка бабла, ушел заниматься делами. Через неделю вернулся.

Comment: @knes, не буду спорить.

Comment: @knes, именно. Яркий тому пример - успешная Травиан.

Comment: Да. До 2й версии была на чистом ахахе. Правда с 2.5 версии там уже ОЧЕНЬ активно юзается JS, что положительно сказалось на играбельности: все-таки на начальном этапе развития счет идет на секунды.

Answer (score 0):

Напиши змейку на js. Уверен будет пользоваться популярностью среди любителей))

Comment: могу свою скинуть. где-то валялась) усовершенствуешь, серверную сторону прикрутишь с рейтингами со всем таким...

Comment: Стратегия, даа... И идейность просто зашибись. Но насчет популярности - согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Из несложного попробуйте сделать клон Ogame. 
1) Главная страничка и регистрация.
2) Неким образом представляете галактику. В простейшем случае используют просто галактику в виде полоски из 255 систем в каждой по 10 планеток. В сложном варианте можете замутить нормальную спиралевидную - довольно просто получается из креста, закрученного по синусоиде например.
3) После реги человека заселяет на стандартную планетку. 
4) На планетке можно улучшать здания примерно как в героях.
5) Можно строить кораблики и устраивать набеги на соседей. Придумайте вариант разведки.
6) Придумайте как игрок может сохранить свои ресурсы и войска от набегов врагов.

Это такой самый простейший вариант. Приметивный и тысячи их, но вполне реальный к исполнению одним программистом.

А если поинтересней - замутите ресурс, на котором можно устраивать соревнования ботов по ELO рейтингу - для начала это могут быть шахматы.
Т.е программист заходит к вам, читает правила соревнования, ограничения по памяти, времени исполнения хода, пишет код, грузит его к вам на сервис и далее бот начинает участвовать в соревнованиях.